# Android how to align a XML for the activity which extends from another activity(with XML)?

Tags: android, extension-methods

I have a BaseActivity with a custom toolbar, it aligns to a XML called activity_base.

I then create a MainActivity extends BaseActivity, it aligns to a XML called activity_main.

When I run the app and intent to MainActivity, it shows activity_base XML, not activity_main. What should I do to show activity_main (and the toolbar from BaseActivity).

Thanks.

Base activity:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //my other codes
}

}
```

Base activity's XML: activity_base

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.cementhddcaibird.astock.CustomToolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my problem: I use activity_main as layout, not show (show activity_base instead)

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a FrameLayout in your BaseActivity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.cementhddcaibird.astock.CustomToolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below=@id/toolbar/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Initialize FrameLayout in BaseActivity:

```
frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
```

Then in MainActivity inflate the XML you made for MainActivity into the container(FrameLayout):

```
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.xml_for_main_activity, frameLayout);
```

instead of

```
setContentView(R.layout.xml_for_main_activity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Override setContentView in MainActivity. That's where you are loading activity_base into MainActivity by error.

Comment: but if I not override, I cannot get the toolbar from base activity, and that's the whole purpose

Comment: you can store it in separate xml file and include it into activities' xmls